# How I get sys.extended_properties SQL in Tedious js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, tedious

I need to get description of the columns in SQL Server 2008 using `Tedius.js` but when I run the query throw the next message :

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: Unknown type: 0
```

This is code :

```
function executeStatement() {
    var query = `select  sc.name as colum, sep.value as description  from sys.tables st
inner join sys.columns sc on st.object_id = sc.object_id
left join sys.extended_properties sep on st.object_id = sep.major_id`

    request = new Request(query, function(err, rowCount) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
        }
    });

    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            console.log(column);

        });
    });


    connection.execSql(request);
}
```